# Failed to Fetch React (Not CORS) - POST Request From Fetch API Cancelled in Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

Pretty new to front-end development- I have a local React front-end that makes a POST request to a Java app deployed on a server.

The way the backend works is, you make a `POST`, and it returns a response ID with a 200 status. The response ID for this is computed separately in a different thread in the backend, so if you `GET` the ID, it returns a 404 status if it hasn't finished computing, or a 200 status if it has finished with a response body.

All the GET and POST requests work fine on a REST client like Postman from my localhost, and I've enabled CORS so my local machine can communicate with the server via `POST` and `GET` perfectly. Also, every time the React UI makes a `GET` request to the server, the data returns perfectly so I doubt it is a CORS issue.

When I try to `POST` from the browser, I keep getting this error on my console:

[image]

To which nothing is sent to the backend and I can't seem to get any response. This is my code:

`POST`

```
export function runSim(
  clientId,
  simulationName,
  totalSims,
  teamRatings,
  fixtureOverrides,
  tieBreakFormat,
  competitionId,
  proBets
) {
  fetch(baseUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(login + ":" + password),
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
      clientId: clientId,
      fixtureOverrides: fixtureOverrides,
      numberOfSimulationsToRun: totalSims,
      simulationName: simulationName,
      teamRatings: teamRatings,
      tieBreakFormat: tieBreakFormat,
      tournamentId: competitionId,
      proBets: proBets,
    }),
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (doc) {
      return doc;
    })
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

The error handler:

```
export function handleError(error) {
  console.error("API call failed. " + error.status);
  alert(error);
  throw error;
}
```

And here is what it looks like on the network:

[image]

I don't understand why the POST request being cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've figured it out, there were these two lines of code when the fetch `POST` was called- I think what happened was the browser rerouted before the fetch was complete, so the network cancelled the request and nothing got sent to the backend.

```
props.history.push("/reports");
window.location.reload();
```

I've commented these two out and it seems to work now. I'll have to think of how to reroute the user to the relevant page but at least I've identified the issue.